# tomcat server depends on rabbitmq server

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am integrating RabbitMQ server in my customized spring-Amqp project as a spring mvc Design based. I did configure in xml for all the Configuration.when the RabbitMq server is down i am trying to start my application,but Tomcat server is not started.
    I want to start my Project through tomcat not depending on RabbitMq
        my configuration is

```
     1. List item

    <rabbit:annotation-driven container-factory="rabbitListenerContainerFactory" />
        <!-- CREATE Queues -->
        <rabbit:queue name="queue.email" durable="true" auto-delete="false"/>
        <rabbit:queue name="queue.sms" durable="true" auto-delete="false"/>
        <rabbit:queue name="queue.newstatus" durable="true" auto-delete="false"/>
        <rabbit:queue name="queue.smsnew" durable="true" auto-delete="false" />
        <rabbit:topic-exchange name="exchange">
        <!--  <rabbit:bindings>
          <rabbit:binding pattern="topic" queue="queue.newstatus"/>
         </rabbit:bindings> -->
        </rabbit:topic-exchange>
        <rabbit:connection-factory 
                               id="connectionFactory" 
                               host="192.168.2.31"  
                               username="guest" 
                               password="guest" 
                               port="5672" 
                               channel-cache-size="100"
                               requested-heartbeat="30"/>
        <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
        <!-- Template Creation -->
        <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" exchange="exchange"/>
        <!-- Listener Creation -->
        <bean id="rabbitListenerContainerFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
            <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="30"/>
            <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="50"/>
            <property name="prefetchCount" value="30"/>
            <property name="defaultRequeueRejected" value="false"/>
            <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
        </bean> 

        <rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" recovery-interval="50000"   acknowledge="none" requeue-rejected="false">
         <rabbit:listener ref="rabbitListenerContainerFactory" queue-names="queue.email" />
         <rabbit:listener ref="rabbitListenerContainerFactory" queue-names="queue.sms" />
        </rabbit:listener-container>
```

I am getting following exception

```
    org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:376)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:573)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1209)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1470)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:907)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1000)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:364)
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem, thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Simply means the broker is not listening on the supplied host/port.

Not related, but you also seem to have completely misunderstood the configuration.

`rabbit:annotation-driven` is for `@RabbitListener` POJO methods; you cannot set the factory as a listener in `<rabbit:listener/>` elements.